# I ran into this error message: 'regparm' is not valid on this platform

Tags: clang, llvm

My Build and Host platforms are X86_64 with suse Linux. My target platform is arm-linux-gnueabi.
I compile the source code with clang of version 3.6.0 . the compiler run  with -target = arm-linux-gnueabi
I failed  with the information below

```
/usr/include/pthread.h:655:6: error: 'regparm' is not valid on this platform
     __cleanup_fct_attribute;
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/bits/pthreadtypes.h:222:50: note: expanded from macro '__cleanup_fct_attribute'
# define __cleanup_fct_attribute __attribute__ ((__regparm__ (1)))
                                                 ^            ~
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

What is your question? 'regparm' is x86-only attribute, so compiler is correct here and your code is broken. Most probably you're not using the correct headers for your target platform.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I compiled some code which can be compiled with gcc. When the compiler switched to clang, clang can't search some paths which gcc searches implicitly. This is why this happened.

Comment: ...and how did you fix that?